# Print a struct in C

Tags: c, printing, struct

I am trying to print a `struct` that is coming as an argument in a function in order to do some debugging.

Is there anyway I could print a structure's contents without knowing what it looks like, i.e. without printing each field explicitly? You see, depending on loads of different `#define`s the structure may look very differently, i.e. may have or not have different fields, so I'd like to find an easy way to do something like `print_structure(my_structure)`.

NetBeans' debugger can do that for me, but unfortunately the code is running on a device I can't run a debugger on.

Any ideas? I suppose it's not possible, but at least there may be some macro to do that at compilation time or something?

Thanks!

Comment: This is now possible in the clang compiler. See [my response to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58721823/219710). (Not sure if SO etiquette is to post a duplicate answer here, or link to the other one)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can always do a hex dump of the structure:

```
#define PRINT_OPAQUE_STRUCT(p)  print_mem((p), sizeof(*(p)))

void print_mem(void const *vp, size_t n)
{
    unsigned char const *p = vp;
    for (size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf("%02x\n", p[i]);
    putchar('\n');
};
```

Comment: This code will also display the contents of the padding bytes. They may contain any value and may be located anywhere inside the struct.

Comment: @Lundin: that's true. But with some knowledge of the compiler, this may still contain useful information. You'd have to know where to look.

Comment: when I compile this function,it tells print_struct.cpp: In function ‘void print_mem(const void*, size_t)’:
print_struct.cpp:14:30: error: invalid conversion from ‘const void*’ to ‘const unsigned char*’ [-fpermissive]

Comment: @young001: that's because it's written in C. In C++, you need an explicit cast to `unsigned char const *`.

Comment: slight better, with grouping and line wrapping: `printf("%02x%s", p[i], i==0 ? "" : i % 16 == 15 ? "\n" : i % 4 == 3 ? " " : "");`

Comment: I strongly disagree with the notion that cramming multiple ternary operators into a parameter is "better."

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing like RTTI in C, only solution (apart from hex dump like above) is to #define dump function together with other #defines, ie.

```
#if _DEBUG

struct { ..... }
#define STRUCT_DUMP(x) printf(.....)

#else

struct { ..... } // other version
#define STRUCT_DUMP(x) printf(.....)    // other version dump

#endif
```