# Writing one byte in struct variable

Tags: c

I'm trying to modify one byte of my structure with the following code :

```
struct example *dev;

PRINT_OPAQUE_STRUCT(dev);
sprintf((char*) dev + 24, "%x",1);
PRINT_OPAQUE_STRUCT(dev);
```

The PRINT_OPAQUE_STRUCT is just printing the content of the structure, and is defined in this other topic :
[Print a struct in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349896/print-a-struct-in-c)

The output of this program is :

> d046f64f20b3fb4f00000000e047f64f00000000ffffffff**00**0000
>   d046f64f20b3fb4f00000000e047f64f00000000ffffffff**31**0000

I don't know why I have the value "31" written and not the value "01" as wanted. I tried to replace the second argument of sprintf with "%01x" but it didn't change anything. Anyone knows why?

Thanks!

Comment: also note that you changed the character after the one you wanted to change to 00. In this case it was already 00 so you dont see it, but if it had been , say, 42 you would have overwritten that to 00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you are formatting the value `1` as a string. That's what `sprintf` does. `0x31` is the character code for the character `'1'`. If you just want to write the byte value `0x01` into your struct, then you don't need `sprintf`. Just do this:

```
*((char*)dev + 24) = 1;
```

or (the same, but with slightly different syntax):

```
((char*)dev)[24] = 1;
```

Note also, like [one comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40871166/writing-one-byte-in-struct-variable/40871214#comment68958072_40871214) says, `sprintf` will not just write one single byte. Since it writes a string, and C strings are null-terminated, it will also write a null character (`'\0'`, `0x00`) right after the `'1'`.

Comment: This. Plus the struct printed out is length 54. Divided by 2, is 27. He's modifying to 24, which is why it's 3 bytes off.

Comment: Plus `sprintf` will be writing a `'\0'` string terminator into the array, which happens to already contain `'\0'` at that location.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know why I have the value "31" written and not the value "01" as wanted.

The reason you see `31` is that your chain of functions interprets the value `1` twice:

- First, `sprintf` interprets it as a character representing a hex digit
- Second, `PRINT_OPAQUE_STRUCT` interprets the value again, now as a hex number

Essentially, `sprintf` converts `1` to its character representation, which is `'1'`. On your system, its code is `0x31`, hence the output that you get.

You need to remove one of these two interpretations to get your code to print `1`. To remove the first interpretation, simply assign `1` to the pointer, like this:

```
((char*)dev)[24] = 1;
```

To remove the second interpretation, print with `%c` instead of `%x` in `PRINT_OPAQUE_STRUCT` (which may not be possible).